Remove specific user from ACL via Powershell
I want to Remove a specific user from ACL via Powershell. Not just the permission of the user for the folder.
I want the user gone from the directory.
The following post discribes my problem perfectly but the solution leads me to an 404 error^^
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/6fbe497e-0ee5-41b5-802b-373466658b48
Does anybody know the solution?
i tried with get-acl and set-acl but these are just setting and removing the permissions not deleting the user itself from the folder.
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "testfolder"

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("testuser","ReadAndExecute","Allow")

$acl.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl -Path "testfolder"

if my folder has lets say test1, test2, test3 users with permissions i now want to remove test1 for example. so not the permissions, i want the user gone from the folder.

Try with $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($AccessRule) instead - it'll remove any ACE with the given user identity from the ACL

U sir, are a genius! How can i close this thread?

I'll post a real answer below :)

Change this method call:
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule)

... to:
$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($AccessRule)

This will remove any rule containing the given user as the identity reference, even if the rest of the ACE details don't match.
